# Integrating over a specific vector field

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, interpolation, line-integrals

I am trying to show that the solution of the following integral is as follows:

Define the stopping time: $C(a) = \inf(u \ge 0 : H(\pi(0) |\mu)-H(\pi(u) | \mu) > a)$

Where $H(\pi(t)|\mu(t))=\sum^{n}_{i=1} \pi_i \log \frac{\pi_i}{\mu_i}$ is the 'Relative Entropy'.

Introduce the vector field: $U_{\mu}(\pi)=\textbf{$\pi$}-\textbf{$\mu$}$
and associated flow:
$$
\frac{d}{du} \pi (u ) = \pi'(u) = -U_\mu(\pi (u ) ) \quad \pi(0) = \pi
$$

Then:
$$
\pi(t+1) = \pi(t) -\int^{\min\{C(a),1\}}_0 U_{\mu(t+1)}(\pi(u)) du\\
=\pi(t)+s(\mu(t+1)-\mu(t))
$$

where $s:=\min\left\{\frac{\frac{a}{|\nabla H(\pi(t)|\mu(t+1))\bullet v|}}{\mu(t+1)-\pi(t)} ,1\right\}$

For clarity, the numerator is:

$$
\frac{a}{|\nabla H(\pi(t)|\mu(t+1))\bullet v|}
$$
the dot product of the directional derivative of the relative entropy and $v$,

Where $v=\frac{\mu(t+1)-\pi(t)}{|\mu(t+1)-\pi(t)|}$

I'm confused by how they can solve the integral:

**My Attempt:**
the flow is a first order ODE, solving for $\pi$ yields:
$$
\pi(t) = e^{-t}(\pi(0)-\mu)+\mu
$$
and the integral:
$$
\int^{\min\{C(a),1\}}_0 U_{\mu(t+1)}(\pi(u)) du=\\
\bigg (\int_0^{\min\{C(a),1\}}\pi_1(u)-\mu_1(t+1)du,......,\int_0^{\min\{C(a),1\}}\pi_n(u)-\mu_n(t+1)du \bigg)
$$
but solving these integrals with my solution to the ODE does not yield anything close to their result. Im confused about where the gradient vector of H comes in to play.. any hints appreciated.

**Update**: I think there may be a typo in the paper and the correct solution should be:
$$
\pi(t)+s(\mu(t+1)-\pi(t))
$$
although I may be wrong. I also think that the solution above has been found by linear interpolation rather than directly solving the integral, I'm new to this method as well so any hints about this would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear: first, $s$ can be viewed as a function of everything that appears inside it: of $\mu$, of $\pi$, of $t$, of $a$. It is not clear from your notations which of these are fixed and which variable. Next, I can only guess that $\pi _i$ means $\pi (i)$. It is not clear in the definition of the relative entropy what is the connection between $t$ and $n$ (I guess that $t$ is a discrete time variable, right?). Finally, it is not clear what you mean by integration *over* a vector field; the only integral above is over $u$, which is a (discrete?) time variable.

Comment: Also, if $u$ is discrete, the integral should be a sum. If $u$ is not discrete, then why is $pi$ calculated only for a discrete variable ("$i$") in the definition of $H$?

Comment: @AlexM. This is from the paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5376

n is the length of the vectors $\pi,\mu$ and t - time is discrete. Yes i thought it should be  a summation as well but this is the way the paper has it and I am trying to figure out how they got to that result

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
The function $s$  is defined  from $\gamma_\pi^*$ which is the free energy (see page 15 http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.5376v1.pdf). They are all functions of $t$ the time variable. so when one reads $$s (\mu(t+1)-\mu(t)) $$ this is meant as a scalar multiplications and not a function evaluation

As one begins with a particular portfolio position one desires to move in a profitable way in the set of portfolios. The movement of the investor's position evolves following an ODE, that means that we have to consider a flow an it's respective vector field.

hope this helps

Comment: I'm still not quite clear how I would evaluate $s(\mu(t+1) - \mu(t) )$??

Comment: You are right, this is scalar multiplications $s = s(t)$ t is a time variable

Comment: you said that s is defined from the free energy, can you explain how to get s through that integral? That is what I am struggling with.. as far as I can tell you are saying that s is expressed in terms of the free energy? but I don't see how they evaluate that integral to get 's'

Comment: could you be more specific in your question?  I didn't read the entire article you mentioned, but I will be glad to discuss it with you any specific issue. I noticed you edited the question, maybe that is a starting point. what do you think?

Comment: fair enough. Well my goal is to take the steps that the paper outlines on page 12, and evaluate it for a specific choice of vector field. The authors do it for the specific example of $\pi - \mu$ and reach a solution on page 28. What I've done so far is to try to solve the ODE posed on 12, and to integrate as above but I am not getting anything near their result. Also, I think my solution to the DE may be wrong, which I am trying to fix up here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1356109/151735